# Function isn't returning anything

Tags: c++

This code is for a homework assignment for my programming class. I'm supposed to input a time in the format of HH:MM AM or HH:MM PM and convert it to military time.

My professor wants us to write the code so that the AM and PM are read regardless of case (Am, pM, am, PM are all acceptable). The conversion function should take the standard time as a string parameter, convert the time into a four-digit military time format (EX. 1:10 AM should be 0110 hours, 5:05 PM should be 1705 hours, etc.), and return a string of the new military time to the main function so the main function can write it in the output.

I'm not receiving any errors anymore, but it seems that when I run the program, nothing is being written my mtime variable. My output is just "Corresponding military time is hours." Can someone help me discover why my conversion function isn't returning the military hours?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

string to24Hour(string);

int main()
{
    string stime, mtime;
    cout << "Enter time: ";
    getline (cin, stime);

    mtime = to24Hour(stime);

    cout << "Corresponding military time is " << mtime << " hours.";
    return 0;
}

string to24Hour(string time)
{
    string hour, minute, period, mtime;
    int colon, space;

    colon = time.find(":");
    space = time.find(" ");

    hour = time.substr(0, colon);
    int ih = stoi(hour);
    minute = time.substr(colon + 1, space);
    period = time.substr(space + 1);
    period = toupper(period[0]) + toupper(period[1]);

    if (period == "AM")
    {
        if (ih = 12)
            mtime = "00" + minute;
        else if (ih < 10)
            mtime = "0" + hour + minute;
        else
            mtime = hour + minute;
        return mtime;
    }
    if (period == "PM")
    {
        if (ih < 12)
        {
            ih = ih + 12;
            hour = to_string(ih);
            mtime = hour + minute;
        }
        else
            mtime = "12" + minute;
        return mtime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your date-parsing code is very brittle, are you sure you can't use regular-expressions?

Comment: Also... **use a debugger!**

Comment: `if (ih = 12)` => `if (ih == 12)`

Comment: @Dai I'm extremely new to programming and I don't have a debugger. Do you have one you recommend? I'm writing and executing all of my code using Code::Blocks. I'm not sure if that means anything.

Comment: @SamFaulkner If you're using CodeBlocks then you already have a debugger. You never noticed the "Debug" item in the menubar nor the Run/Debug buttons in the toolbar?!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If I'm not mistake, since I ih is an int variable I only need one = sign.

Comment: @Dai As I said earlier, I'm still new to programming and I'm not all that familiar with CodeBlocks and what it all has to offer. I'm definitely going to look into it.

Comment: @SamFaulkner With built-in types, `=` is always assignment. `==` is always equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Found part of the problem. When I was doing that toupper line with both characters, it was turning AM in AA with an accent over the 2nd A. Since it wasn't AM or PM, nothing was executed. Everything is working now!

Here is the updated code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

string to24Hour(string);

int main()
{
    string stime, mtime;
    cout << "Enter time: ";
    getline (cin, stime);

    mtime = to24Hour(stime);

    cout << "Corresponding military time is " << mtime << " hours.";
    return 0;
}

string to24Hour(string time)
{
    string hour, minute, period, mtime;
    int colon, space;

    colon = time.find(":");
    space = time.find(" ", 4);

    hour = time.substr(0, colon);
    int ih = stoi(hour);
    minute = time.substr(colon + 1, 2);
    period = time.substr(space + 1);
    period = toupper(period[0]);

    if (period == "A")
    {
        if (ih < 10)
            mtime = "0" + hour + minute;
        else if (ih = 12)
            mtime = "00" + minute;
        else
            mtime = hour + minute;
        return mtime;
    }
    if (period == "P")
    {
        if (ih < 12)
        {
            ih = ih + 12;
            hour = to_string(ih);
            mtime = hour + minute;
        }
        else
            mtime = "12" + minute;
        return mtime;
    }
}
```

Comment: `else if (ih = 12)` is still wrong if you want a comparison and not an assignment. To compare write `else if (ih == 12)`.